# Unity Z-Order. How can I put all sprite upon ground but not effects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shaderlab

I have many soldiers(600+) on a battleground. So all soldier should be a 2d sprite for the performance issue.

[image]

As you can see the foot of the horse is underground, so to solve this, I turn off the `ZWrite` in ground's shader.

```
ZWrite Off
```

But when I turn off the `ZWrite` of ground, another issue happened, some effect's underground part is been showed, which is not I want to see.[image]

I also tried to modify the depth offset of the soldier shader, but it seems to big to move soldier upon the ground, and all soldier will upon on effect too, that's not I want.

```
Offset 0, -100000
```

So, How can I achieve this? Make all sprite soldier upon the ground and not show the underground part of effects?

Comment: Do you need "underground part" in the future? If not can you remove it from another app? (I assume it is also a 2d animation)

Comment: @Thalthanas It's complicated, because effects can be made in particles or mesh. You can't force to hide when they underground.